# Modularity and tables on Rspec (RoR)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, tdd

I'm doing an Rspec feature to test some user story and I'm getting the error message:

```
Internal Server Error uninitialized constant Tree::MY_BRAnCH
```

Now, I know the test fails because the table "trees" doesn't have the proper rows but only fails when I run the suite test.

```
  RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rspec spec/
```

pointing to the articles_spec.rb file as responsible. But if I run just the feature file:

```
RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rspec spec/features/articles_spec.rb
```

the test pass fine. Digging in the code I see other developer made a test with the indication:

```
before { truncate(Tree) }
```

So that test is executed first and is removing the data in the table.

My question is: how can avoid this?  Need I to reload all the database before each rspec file?

or what policy should we follow to be sure the rspec tests are not affecting other developers?

Answer (score 1):

It seems unlikely that truncating a database table would cause an `uninitialized constant` error.  More likely, `articles_spec.rb` causes `Tree::MY_BRAnCH` to be defined.  That's why running `articles_spec.rb` alone passes.  When you run the whole spec suite, something tries to use the constant before it has been defined, hence `uninitialized constant`.

One solution could be to search your codebase for usages of `Tree::MY_BRAnCH` and make sure that it has been defined before it is used.  You may need to learn about one or more of the following code loading techniques:

- [`Kernel#require`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Kernel.html#method-i-require)
- [`Kernel#autoload`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Kernel.html#method-i-autoload)
- [`ActiveSupport::Autoload`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Autoload.html#method-i-autoload)